# Is the Binomial Theorem extendable to other fields?

Tags: field-theory, binomial-theorem

I very well know that the Binomial Theorem can be extended from an integer power, to a rational exponent, any real number and perhaps to the complex field with $z^w=e^{w \cdot ln(z)}$ or $(x+iy)^{u+iv}=\bigl((x+iy)^{iv}\bigr)^u$. Is this theorem extendable to any other field $\mathbb F $ ?

Comment: What is your version of the binomial theorem for when the exponent is say $\pi$ ?

Comment: Have you heard of the *generalized* binomial theorem for real exponent ?

Comment: For example: $(1+x)^\pi=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\pi\cdot(\pi-1)\cdot(\pi-2)\cdot\cdot\cdot(\pi-k)}{k!}x^k$

Comment: Does your formula hold for $x=0,1,2,..$?

Comment: @Michael Morrow Now that you mention it, I rechecked the formula and I mistakenly offsetted the coefficients by 1, the product should be until $(a-k+1)$. It should also be mentioned that this particular example only converges for $|x|<1$. c.f. <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem>

Comment: I see. Well, you'd first have to define what exponentiation *means* for arbitrary elements of your field $\mathbb{F}$. As you know, this can be done using the exponential function in the case of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. Then you could try to formulate a binomial theorem.

Comment: @Michael Morrow Well I know there is the concept of <<exponential field>>, but field theory is not a subject I'm well acquainted beyond undergraduate introduction; I don't know the possible difficulties one may encounter depending on the field, like how order or characteristic may affect its existence or <<well definedness>>